# Magento 2 - Getting user role

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, user-roles, role

I would like to get the Role of the user logged in.

I'm trying to use the `\vendor\magento\module-user\Model\User.php` class, but all results give me null or empty.

I'm trying to use `\vendor\magento\module-authorization\Model\Role.php`, but the same happens, all empty.

I have achieved getting the userName of the user logged in, which might help, with this class: `\vendor\magento\module-backend\Model\Auth\Session.php`

I have checked the database, and in the `authoritzation_role` I have:

[image]

Where the `parent_id` refers to the 3 roles I have created:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Am I calling the right classes? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below code.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\User\Model\UserFactory $userFactory)
{
    $this->userFactory = $userFactory;
}

public function getAdminRole()
{
 $roleName = $this->userFactory->create()->getRole()->getRoleName();
}
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: hey @Raul, did it work for you?